# Magento soap api add product with custom options value in shopping cart

Tags: php, magento, soap

I am using soap custom api for create and add product in cart. I have some custom options associated with the product.
I have to add a product in cart with custom options. I have tried it but it always gives me Error: Please specify the product required option(s).
I have implemented below mentioned two codes for this but both are not working.[image]

$arrProducts = array(
            array(
                "product_id" => "26",
                "qty" => 2,
                "sku" => "CHEERCARDS-HAPPY BIRTHDAY-MEOW",
                "quantity" => 2,
                "bundle_option" => array(
                    "111" => "toemailid@test.com",
                    "112" => "fromemailid@test.com",
                    "110" => "QR Code",
                    "109" => "Simple message",
                ),
            ),
        )

and

$arrProducts = array(
            array(
                "product_id" => "26",
                "qty" => 1,
                "sku" => "CHEERCARDS-HAPPY BIRTHDAY-MEOW",
                "quantity" => 1,
                'options' => array ( 
                    0 => array(
                        'key' =>  111,
                        'value' =>  '1001'
                    ),
                    1 => array(
                        'key' =>  112,
                        'value' =>  '1001'
                    ),
                    2 => array(
                        'key' =>  110,
                        'value' =>  '1001'
                    ),
                    3 => array(
                        'key' =>  109,
                        'value' =>  '1001'
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        )

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to to give product id and sku with quantity and qty. just try this code.

```
$arrProducts = array( array( "product_id" => "26", "qty" => 2, "bundle_option" => array( "111" => "toemailid@test.com", "112" => "fromemailid@test.com", "110" => "QR Code", "109" => "Simple message" ) ) );
```

This works for me. I hope it 'll work for you also.

Comment: This also work for me if I don't have custom options set with my product. But when I add any custom option with the product and try to add product using magento cart api then it gives me "Error: Please specify the product required option(s).".

Comment: only product_id and qty required.

Comment: what custom options you want to set?

Comment: But my client added a custom options with required validations that's why I must need to send option values along with the product_id and qty. But I am not able to get the proper post structure for add product with custom option using "cart_product.add" method.

Comment: Manage product -> select any product from list ->  Custom Options -> add new option -> select inputType as field and keep it mandatory.
then try to add product using cart_product.add in magento soap api.

Comment: i don't think , you can add custom options with product when you are adding product in cart so first add custom option in product then add the product in cart.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62673/discussion-between-neeraj-sharma-and-lokesh-jain).

Comment: I have fixed this using :
$arrProducts = array(
   array(
    "product_id" => "41",
    "qty" => 2,
    "sku" => "CHEERCARDS-HAPPY BIRTHDAY-MEOW",
    "options" => array(
     "111" => "toemailid@test.com",
     "112" => "fromemailid@test.com",
     "110" => "QR Code",
     "109" => "Simple message",
    ),
   ),
  )